# Multiple sites on iis with same ip and port

Tags: iis

I am trying to create multiple sites on IIS server that will use the same ip and port. The domains are site1.com, site2.com and site3.com. My hosts file is set as follows 127.0.0.1   site1, 127.0.0.1   site2, and 127.0.0.1   site3.com. I can browse the sites locally and they resolve correctly. I want to be able to access these sites from the world wide web. How will I construct the ip address for each site?

I get an address bar error when I try the following address.

ie http://55.555.55.5:80:www.site1.com

I've tried every combination I can think of but nothing is working.

Comment: Yes, it has an external ip. My router is forwarding 192.168.1.4:80 to my computer. I turned off my firewall until I can get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently browsing via the *localhost* ip (127.0.0.1). First of all you need to expose your web server to the internet, which may involve adding port forwarding on your firewall. Secondly, you need you create the appropriate records in DNS so that the desired hostnames point to that external ip address (of course this requires that you registered the domains site1.com etc. in the first place).

Comment: My firewall is off. When a call is made to my server for site1.com the url must contain some information as to which site my server needs to serve.

Comment: @DaleWahl, so hackers could access your machine without any security measures? That doesn't quite seem right. Your router may have a firewall capability to it for where there is another firewall here.

Comment: @DaleWahl Erm, yes. the url `http://site1.com/something` does contain the information that your server needs to serve site1. Recall that a user-agent will first extract `site1.com` from the url, determine (e.g., by DNS) the ip to connect, make a tcp connection to port 80 (because no `:port` was added) and send a request `GET /something HTTP/1.1` accompanied by a header `Host: site1.com`, and both these pieces of information are then evaluated by your webserver. The fact that `site1.com` occurs as `Host:` header is (in well-behaved use cases) directly caused by `site1.com` occuring in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Contact an ISP or hosting provider to give you a static IP that can be used for outside traffic. Be aware that there may be fees involved depending on how much traffic you put through as well as what firewall changes may have to be made where the sites will be in the end.

[IANA](http://www.iana.org/) would be the organization that assigns addresses at the public level that ISPs and hosting providers buy for the part you are missing here. [IP Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) may also be helpful as "555" isn't a valid value for an octet in such an address as each octet is in the range from 0 to 255 and some have specific meanings.